# compare windows server for patch/update/hotfix installs

Tags: windows

Are there any tools that can be used to connect to windows 2008 servers, and get a comparison of the installed patches/updates on the servers, showing what is installed on one and not on the other?

This is to help isolate an issue we are seeing on a specific windows server, in a load balanced setup. There is a certain performance/locking issue, which is mitigated whenever one of the servers is disabled.

Please share, if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On a wider scale... WSUS.  Depends on the scale though.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [Win32_QuickFixEngineering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa394391.aspx) WMI class to get a list of hotfixes installed.  Dump the results to an XML file and then use a diff tool (WinMerge, P4Merge, Beyond Compare, etc...).